# Do I need WinRE partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I recently installed Windows 10 after my Windows 7 installation got corrupted (yes, my data was backed up). I used the command prompt available in the Windows Installation USB to reformat the drive using DISKPART. By default, the drive was formatted as an MBR partition, which I later learned has been deprecated in favor of GPT. I also learned that I could use Microsoft's MBR2GPT tool to convert the partition to GPT after installation, so I continued the installation using MBR.

After the installation I used the MBR2GPT tool to convert my MBR partition to GPT; however, it failed in creating the WinRE partition. After inspecting my disk using windows computer management utility, it appears that I only have a primary partition and an EFI partition.

In summary, I have the following questions.

- I do not see a MSR partition using the computer management utility.
  Is this a problem?
- Do I need the WinRE partition? If it is just for
  launching windows in recovery mode, then will a recovery USB suffice?

NOTE: My Windows 10 system boots just fine. The absence of a MSR and WinRE partition does not seem to have effected my installation.

Comment: No, you do not. Just do reagentc /disable and remove the Recovery partition. For MSR keep it, I though do not have it on my NVMe drive, only in my other GPT drive without an OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't, you can make a System Repair disc to do the same thing, its just a windows recovery environment where you can possibly repair issues with the OS. Its more of a convenience than a necessity.

To make a Repair Disc In Windows 10 go to Control Panel (icon view selected) and click Backup and Restore icon, then on the left side click Create a System Repair Disc.

When you have trouble with W10 you can boot from this disc and have some repair tools.